# Change TabText appearance based on Stack or Inline tabs

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to change the style of the text in the Actionbar Tabs. When they are stacked (below the actionbar) I want the text to be black and when they are inside the actionbar, I want the text to be white. I have customized the background successfully based on this, but cannot figure out how to do it, if it's even possible.